# Why isn't Hogwarts platform's name "Platform Nine and Half" instead of "Platform Nine and Three-Quarters"?

Tags: harry-potter

Students hit at the middle between Platform 9 and Platform 10 of King's Cross Railway Station.

[image]

So, why isn't the platform name "*Platform Nine **and a Half***"?

What's the point of making it more confusing when there are no other fractional platform numbers to occupy the possibility?

Comment: Where does it ever say 'exactly'?

Comment: @Mithrandir Removed the word.. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Because it's just slightly further down

Comment: Out of universe answer: Because it's more whimsical that way.

Comment: @Valorum That pillar looks in the middle.

Comment: @Discovery - The brick pillar thing is entirely a movie invention. The books describe a "metal barrier".

Comment: They hit the barrier at different parts, Fred is much closer to the left hand side than George so position clearly doesn't make too much difference.

Comment: ...Obviously "three quarters" meant the entrance was to be approached from the side closer to platform 10, while "one quarter" would be the opposite direction, from platform nine, and "a half" would be simply perpendicular.  Pillars or dividers have four sides, after all.

Comment: @Megha You can see clearly in the gif that they are hitting the perpendicular side. BTW, nice interpretation of fractional numbers of platforms.

Comment: What's the point of making it more confusing  : That's the joke... I mean the point.It is mean to be more confusing.

Answer (score 11):

Per [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/platform-nine-and-three-quarters), the number was chosen by JKR for its *whimsy value* rather than because it actually makes sense.

> *In choosing the number of the concealed platform that would take young
> witches and wizards to boarding school, I decided that it would have
> to be a number between those of the Muggle platforms - therefore, it
> was clearly a fraction. This raised the interesting question of how
> many other fractional platforms lay between the whole-numbered
> platforms at King's Cross, and I concluded that were probably quite a
> few. Although these are never mentioned in the book, I like to think
> that it is possible to take a version of the Orient Express off to
> wizard-only villages in continental Europe (try platform seven and a
> half), and that other platforms may be opened on an as-required-basis,
> for instance for large, one-off events such as Celestina Warbeck
> concerts (see your ticket for details).*
>
> ***The number nine and three-quarters presented itself without much
> conscious thought, and I liked it so much that I took it at once. It
> is the 'three-quarters' that makes it, of course.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Platform Nine and Three-Quarters By J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/platform-nine-and-three-quarters)</sup></sub>

Comment: Means, there were indeed other fractional platform numbers.